# Do we need to fsync the parent directory in UBIFS for atomic *and* durable file updates

Tags: linux, filesystems, fsync, ubifs

Here's the [typical and well-known approach](https://thunk.org/tytso/blog/2009/03/15/dont-fear-the-fsync/#atomicity-not-durability) for **atomic** file updates:

```
fd = open(“foo.new”, O_WRONLY);
write(fd, buf, bufsize);
fsync(fd);
close(fd);
rename(“foo.new”, “foo”);
```

In general, if we also want **durability** (i.e. a guarantee that the *new* version of the file will be available if there is a crash), then we also need to call `fsync` on the parent directory.

Question: Is this also needed for UBIFS? The [documentation](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubifs.html#L_writeback) says:

> fsync() may be called for directories - it synchronizes the directory
>   inode meta-data. [...]
>
> The fdatasync() call for directories is "no-op" in UBIFS and all UBIFS
>   operations which change directory entries are synchronous.

If I am reading correctly, the latter ("all UBIFS operations which change directory entries are synchronous") seems to imply that calling `fsync` on the parent dir would not be necessary. However my tests seem to indicate otherwise. Am I misreading the docs, or is this information outdated?

Comment: The doc is confusing. fdatasync is usually done on file and not directory fds. The ubifs_fsync() function in the code seems to be identical for file and directory operations. You should perhaps ask on their mailing list.

Comment: Looks like you got a reply :) http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-mtd/2018-December/086225.html

Comment: Indeed. So it looks like the docs are misleading in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the MTD mailing list; seems that the documentation is ambiguous, and that [calling `fsync` on the parent dir is necessary](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-mtd/2018-December/086225.html) as in other file systems.